# How to access a variable value from page to other

Tags: flutter

```
statefull page1 {
 bool myBool = false ;
}


statefull page2 {
 print(page1().myBool ) // this print the value but the printed value does not print the update one 
}
```

i mean if `myBool` changed to true it always print false in page 2 ..

note: page2 is stack page above page1 and page 1 still mounted and i want print myBool value from page 2 as if i do it in page 1

Comment: don't start using get as suggested answer below `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlIgy4es5Ts`

Answer (score 0):

When we use `page1()` we are creating a new instance and that's why it is getting false  everytime.

You can make it static which will be on class variable but it won't be for updating ui.

It will be easy for you using callback method https://stackoverflow.com/a/75006895/10157127

If you don't need to update value from page2, just pass the value as parameter.
or better state management solutions.

Comment: i don't want to update myBool within page 2 .. i only want to know it's current updated value (based on it's original/parent instance ) . you can imagine myBool get changed from the server while user currently visiting page 2 , so based on this changed i want make action in page 2 .
personally i don't like make it globally or static  . if you have a way to get it's update value (based on it's original/parent instance ) as mentioned  will be thankful

Comment: create the `myBool` on page2.
try passing instance `page2({required this.myBool})`

Answer (score 0):

use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package from pub.dev

GetX is an extra-light and powerful solution for Flutter. It combines high-performance state management, intelligent dependency injection, and route management quickly and practically.

Learn [GetX documentation](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/) and you can access a variable value from page to other very easy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).